# How to change "+" to "-" in URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, preg-replace

I want to change "+" to "-" in URL in php application by using htaccess

Example
http://hddir.com/videos/kodak+black
To
http://hddir.com/videos/kodak-black

My htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ / [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+) search.php?q=$1&order=$2&type=$3&ptk=$4
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /search(?:\.php)?\?q=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ videos/%1? [R=302,L]
# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one         
RewriteRule ^videos/(.+)$ search.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^video/(.+).html$ watch.php?v=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
#######Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick by redirecting every domain with a plus in it permanently to the same domain but a minus instead of plus:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: change it to this RewriteRule ^(.*)\+(.*)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]

Comment: Changed it accordingly. Forgot to escape "+", sorry.